# Undefined method in Create using build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been going back and forth on this and can't work out why I'm getting an error with Rails 4!

I have 3 models, show below.

I'm try to create a section associated with a project and getting a NoMethodError of **undefined method `sections' for nil:NilClass**

From what I can tell, I'm going through the same process as when I create a project associated to a current_user.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :projects
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :sections
 end
```

**section.rb**

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :project
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Dr::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :sections
  end

  resources :sections

  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
end
```

**sections_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @section = Section.new
end

def create
  @project = params[:project_id]
  @section = @project.sections.build section_params
  respond_to do |format|
    if @section.save
      format.html { redirect_to project_path(@section), :notice => 'Section was successfully created.' }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @section, :status => :created, :location => @section }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @section.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
def section_params
  params.require(:section).permit(:name)
end
```

**new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for [@project, @section] do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

Comment: What is the content of your `@project` variable in the create action?

Comment: @TomášDundáček I assumed I was doing that to pass the Project to the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for which project u have this form

```
= simple_form_for [@project, @section] do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

i mean from where u are getting @project, if your form is in seperate view as u had said in new.html.haml then you new method must hhave @project also

```
def new
  @section = Section.new
  @project = current_user.projects.find(:id)  # pass an id for which u are creating section
end
```

Comment: Thank you, combined with @Mattherick, this did the job. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the create action in your controller like following:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
  @section = @project.sections.new section_params
  respond_to do |format|
    if @section.save
      format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project), :notice => "Section for #{@project.name} was successfully created." }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @section }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @section.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This returns an error unfortunately, "Couldn't find Project without an ID", my route is '/projects/1/sections/new'